# What AWS quotas do I need for SageMaker Asynchronous Inference Endpoints to be able to scale?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I want to deploy a model using an Asynchronous Inference endpoint which will auto-scale. However, I cannot find the information about what quotas are required for this to work without running out of resources.

Does scaling require some specific type of quotas, so that multiple jobs can be executed in parallel on different instances of the inference container?

It really isn't clear in the documentation whether quotas apply to Asynchronous Inference endpoints or not. Clearly, they apply to real-time inference endpoints, but Asynchronous Inference documentation does not seem to mention about it at all...

Answer (score 0):

AutoScaling with Async endpoints is not different than autoscaling with other Inference options i.e your AWS Quotas need to reflect the right amount of instances you wish to scale to. For instance, if you configure the min and maximum instance count in your Async autoscaling config shown below you would need a 5 instances available at your disposal.  [ [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference-autoscale.html) ]

```
response = client.register_scalable_target(
    ServiceNamespace='sagemaker', 
    ResourceId=resource_id,
    ScalableDimension='sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount', # The number of EC2 instances for your Amazon SageMaker model endpoint variant.
    MinCapacity=0,
    MaxCapacity=5
)
```

NOTE - I work for AWS SageMaker, but my opinions are my own.